# INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY in send email method

Tags: opportunity, partner-portal, singleemailmessage

We a custom object(child) which is a detail of Opportunity (OWD = private). Whenever a partner user creates this child record sendEmail is method is invoked from the trigger. We have field (lookUPuser__c) on the child object which is a look up to user object. But when the trigger is fired it errors out at the sendEmail line with the error:

> System.EmailException: SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0;
>   first error: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, invalid cross reference id:
>   []

I have made sure that the lookupUser__c has access to the opportunity before the send email method is called. But If I set the targetObjectId as `createdBYId` (partneruser himself) then the there is no error. I am totally clueless as to what to do next.

```
//I am adding the lookUpUser__c in the opportunityShare object with Edit access.
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage(); 
mail.setTargetObjectId(trigger.new[0].lookUPuser__c);
mail.saveAsActivity = false;
mail.setTemplateId('00XJ0000000dceYMAW');
mail.setWhatId(trigger.new[0].Id);
mail.setOrgWideEmailAddressId('0D2J00000005P9s');
Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.Email[] { mail } ); // erroring out here.

//this piece is working fine
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage(); 
mail.setTargetObjectId(trigger.new[0].createdById);
mail.saveAsActivity = false;
mail.setTemplateId('00XJ0000000dceYMAW');
mail.setWhatId(trigger.new[0].Id);
mail.setOrgWideEmailAddressId('0D2J00000005P9s');
Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.Email[] { mail } );

<messaging:emailTemplate subject="Hi " recipientType="User" relatedToType="child__c">
    <messaging:htmlEmailBody>
        Dear  {!recipient.FirstName}, 

        {!relatedTo.Name} Blah Blah
    </messaging:htmlEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

Comment: What line number is the error happening on?

Comment: Never mind. I just seen the " erroring out here" comment in the code

Comment: The first thing I would do is to add some debugging to make sure that trigger.new[0].lookUPuser__c is set. Then using the Id that should be printed out in the debugging, navigate to that record in the UI to verify that you have read access on it. You may find that the user has no access to that record.

Comment: @BarCotter: The values are setting up properly in the mail object. Also when the lookUPuser__c is set as a sys Admin user even then it errors out..

Comment: Did you try navigate to that user record to make sure that you have access to it?

Comment: yes, I have checked it out, the user has access to the record. I have also checked out the sharing table for the opportunity and the name appears there as well..

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that your partner user has no access to the User object you are trying to send the email to.

Whilst you have access to the Child object, they can't traverse over to the User object.

This is probably because the Default External Access for the User object is Private.

Check your Sharing Settings and consider changing that to Public Read Only or setting up Sharing rules.

You need to consider the security/privacy issues of this change however.

Comment: The default external access is only available if the communities is enabled. But I'm working on a org where the communities is disabled. Not sure how to about resolving this issue.

Comment: In that case, it's possible you just don't have access to the User object as the running user, but I haven't confirmed that for you.  I'm working on the basis that 'Invalid cross reference' often has come up for me relating to records I don't have access to.

Answer (score 0):

Seems it is too late for me to answer this question. But just resolved a similar issue. Basically, this error means you are assigning a wrong Id into some field. So it seems to me that this line:

```
mail.setTargetObjectId(trigger.new[0].lookUPuser__c);
```

would have probably caused the issue. If not, check for other Id assignments.